# Deserialize Json to C# bool

Tags: c#, json

I need help with a very simple question. 
How can I deserialize the json below to a C# bool without creating a wrapping root object.
Thanks.

```
f
{"valid":false}
0
```

Comment: What are the f and 0?

Comment: @Liam Most likely chunked output from an HTTP server?

Answer (score 10):

If you are using [Json.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/json):

```
string json = @"{""valid"":true}";

var jo = JObject.Parse(json);
bool flag = jo.SelectToken("valid").Value<bool>()
```